# .gitignore ignore the Intellij IDEA

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a question about `.gitignore`.
[image]

I use Intellij IDEA to automatically generate what folders to ignore. In `.gitignore` it wrote `../.idea/`. In the git status view, I still can see it:

[image]

Comment: Just google gitignore jetbrains. Copy paste the result into your gitignore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your `git status` shows `../.idea`, that means your `.gitignore` is one folder below:

```
/path/to/repo
   .idea
   asubfolder
     .gitignore
```

Make sure your `.gitignore` is at the same level as .idea, and use:

```
.idea/
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just put .idea without ../ in the .gitignore

Answer (score 0):

Here it is what you generally need IDEA, Eclipse, NetBeans, target folder... in `.gitignore`

```
target/
!.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.jar

### STS ###
.apt_generated
.classpath
.factorypath
.project
.settings
.springBeans

### IntelliJ IDEA ###
.idea
*.iws
*.iml
*.ipr

### NetBeans ###
nbproject/private/
build/
nbbuild/
dist/
nbdist/
.nb-gradle/
```

Be sure after this you run `git rm -r --cached .`

Comment: Why is `maven-wrapper.jar` excluded here? Why isn't the pom self-contained?

Comment: @PeterHall actually  maven-wrapper.jar  can be used for running maven project without maven installed/not find in the relative path. For example; spring-boot project automatic installation for granting encapsulated built setup.